# jQuery with noConflict and Assignment of noConflict Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dynamic

I've been working with 2 different versions of jQuery on one page and am trying to utilitze the 'noConflict.'
If I establish a variable for each of the jQuery versions, (examples: $a and $b), would I replace all of the $'s with '$a' and '$b?'

for example (a snippet of the full code [which appears at the bottom]).. wasn't sure where to put the $b's.

```
<script>
$b(document).ready(function() {
function clone(){
  var $cloned = $('table tr:last').clone();
  var oldIndex = $cloned.find('input').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
  var newIndex = parseInt(oldIndex,10)+1;
  $cloned.find('input').each(function(){
     var newName = $(this).attr('name').replace(oldIndex, newIndex);
     $(this).attr('name', newName);
  });
  $cloned.insertAfter('table tr:last');
}
$('p.add-btn').click(clone)

;
</script>
```

Below, is the HTML form code, along with the jQuery clone function, along with the date picker functions.  Currently, when I enable one, the other function does not work.  Thanks for any leads.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>var $a = jQuery.noConflict(true);  //sets up 1st version of jquery to run for Zebra datepicker</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="zebra_datepicker/js/zebra_datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="zebra_datepicker/css/default.css" type="text/css">
<script>
$a(document).ready(function() {

    $a('#SubmissionDate').Zebra_DatePicker({
        view: 'years',
        readonly_element: true
        });

    $a('#ClassYear').Zebra_DatePicker({
        view: 'years',
        format: 'Y',
        readonly_element: true
        });


 });
</script>


<script>
$b(document).ready(function() {
function clone(){
  var $cloned = $('table tr:last').clone();
  var oldIndex = $cloned.find('input').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
  var newIndex = parseInt(oldIndex,10)+1;
  $cloned.find('input').each(function(){
     var newName = $(this).attr('name').replace(oldIndex, newIndex);
     $(this).attr('name', newName);
  });
  $cloned.insertAfter('table tr:last');
}
$('p.add-btn').click(clone)

;
</script>



<table id="FormLayout" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td class="FormLabel" width="100px"><strong>Class Year*</strong></td>
<td width="100px"><input type="text" id="ClassYear" name="ClassYear_1" class="required" value="<%= Request.form("ClassYear") %>" tabindex="4" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>
 <button type="button" id="add-btn">Add Class Year</button>
 </td></tr>              
 <tr>
 <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="FormSubmit" value="True" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="8" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I establish a variable for each of the jQuery versions, (examples: $a and $b), would I replace all of the $'s with '$a' and '$b?'*

Yes you have to, Starting to the line where you declare a variable pointing forward you can only invoke a jQuery function/methods using that variable declaration.

```
//Assume that by this time there is 'noConflict' declared variable you can still invoke a method of jquery using this.
$().

//But as you declared a 'noConflict' variable
var $a = jQuery.noConflict();
//$() would return undefined.
```

Comment: Would the $'s within the function also be replaced with $a?

for example, would all of the $'s below be changed to $a

`var $cloned = $('table tr:last').clone();`

Comment: @buck1112 yes, all jQuery method/function call should be changed after the declaration.

Comment: Thanks. 
In the code below, would the $cloned remain as it is?
`jQuery.noConflict(true);
function clone2(){
  var $cloned = $('table tr:last').clone();`

Comment: nope you don't have to change it, $cloned is not a jquery function/method. it is your own declaration..normally it is advice that when you name a jquery object you should name them with '$' e.g., $variableName this will indicate that it is a jquery object.. but it was not required, its just a convention :) .

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  ..helps to clarify the naming conventions tremendously. :)

Comment: I am glad that I can help you out .. if this answers your question don't forget to mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

1. Include the original version.
2. Then include the version required by `Zebra datepicker`.

Just after, you don't need any conflict handling, just call your plugin by using `$`. To make sure `console.log('$.fn.jquery');`

After using your plugin you need to call `oldV = jQuery.noConflict( true );` to restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded. In the next code just use `$` normally.